# Loop through sheets and particular cells on sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel sheet with overview (first tab),
there are two columns - company_name and price
and there are about 50 following sheets (named as individual companies).

I'd like to generate the overview automatically.

So when new sheet with company name is added it will be added in the
overview (first sheet) under its column and when price is added it will
be added in the overview under its column. Price is always in the cell
D21 on sheets identified by company names.

So in the first (overview) sheet, there will be a mapping

```
company_name | price
AAA (second sheet name) | secondsheet!D21
BBB (third sheet name)  | thirdsheet!D21
CCC (fourth sheet name) | fourthsheet!D21
... etc.
```

How can I insert such a formula or create event driven macro for it?

Comment: `Can I insert such a formula?` not really, there are some convoluted methods using named ranges. `Or create event driven macro for it?` Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the worksheet code of your first sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim i As Long
Me.Range("A2:B1000").ClearContents
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    Me.Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets(i).Name
    Me.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!D21"
Next i
End Sub
```

Now every time the worksheet is activate it will clear and repopulate the list with the correct formula.  It iterates the sheets and fills the cells with the name and the formula pointing at D21.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a macro to iterate through all the sheets and insert appropriate rows in the overview sheet.

Iterate through sheets: `For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets`

In this loop `s.Name` will be the sheet name and it should be easy enough to create a row in the overview sheet with a formula which refers to that sheet's D21 value.